# RigidBody.velocity isn't 0 even when idle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry if my english is bad, im Brazilian :P

Well, i have a advanced movement system to my player with acceleration using RigidBody.AddForce and slowdown using the linear drag.

Its everything working well, but when the player is idle, the RigidBody.velocity in x axis go crazy, the player is not moving in the transform component, but i want to add animations to the player and i can't detect if the player is idle or moving because this.

This is disturbing me a lot, i search in other questions but seems that just happens with me, someone can help? Here is the code:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Components")]
    public Rigidbody2D body;
    public SpriteRenderer sprite;
    public Animator anim;

    [Header("Movement Variables")]
    public float aceleration;
    public float MaxSpeed = 7f;
    public float linearDrag;
    float move;
    bool changingDirection;

    [Header("Jump Variables")]
    public float JumpForce;
    public float airLinearDrag = 2.5f;
    bool isGrounded;

    [Header("Ground Check")]
    public GameObject GroundCheck;
    public LayerMask GroundLayer;
    public float radius;
    public bool DrawGizmos;

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        LinearDrag();

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
            Jump();

        if(move > 0 && sprite.flipX || move < 0 && !sprite.flipX)
            sprite.flipX = !sprite.flipX;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        body.AddForce(new Vector2(move * aceleration, 0f));
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.transform.position, radius, GroundLayer);

        if(Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.x) > MaxSpeed)
            body.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(body.velocity.x) * MaxSpeed, body.velocity.y);
    }

    void Move()
    {
        move = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if(body.velocity.x > 0 && move < 0 || body.velocity.x < 0 && move > 0)
            changingDirection = true;
        else
            changingDirection = false;
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        body.drag = 0f;
        body.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    void LinearDrag()
    {
        if(!isGrounded)
            body.drag = airLinearDrag;
        else
        {
            if(Mathf.Abs(move) == 0 && Mathf.Abs(body.velocity.x) > 0 && isGrounded || changingDirection && isGrounded)
                body.drag = linearDrag;
            else
                body.drag = 0f;
        }
    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        if(DrawGizmos)
            Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(GroundCheck.transform.position, radius);
    }
```

Comment: Does this still happen if you remove `body.drag = 0f;`?

Comment: yes, i tried but still happening

Answer (score 0):

When you're checking whether something is equal to zero, you should use Mathf.Epsilon instead of zero because of the way that computers store floating points.  Often a computer stores zero as an infinitesimally small floating point number -- too small to effect some things, but enough to throw off a test of whether some value is equal to zero.

For example, you would change

```
if(Mathf.Abs(move) == 0)
```

to

```
if(Mathf.Abs(move) < Mathf.Epsilon)
```

And in some cases, you might have to use a number larger than Mathf.Epsilon.  I just discovered that the reason my player wouldn't go into idle animation on some surfaces was that his rigidbody.velocity.x was intermittently higher than Mathf.Epsilon, throwing him into a 'running' state for a millisecond, long enough to stop the idle animation over and over again before it was visibly working.  So I substituted my own epsilon number in place of Mathf.Epsilon.  The number that worked for me was 0.00005f, but you'll have to experiment to find the right number for your situation.